# How to click on listview item after change it to different to layout?

Tags: android, listview, layout-inflater

When I click on listview, it will change that item to different layout. But after that I can't click on that item anymore. What am I supposed to do? Please help me. Thank you.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null || convertView.getTag() == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_mainlist_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.rl_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectedItem(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext.getApplicationContext(), DetailActivity.class);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    if (this.clk_position == position) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_mainlist_item_p, null);
        return view;
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what do you want actually. So that we could have understood the scenario.

Comment: I'm sorry. Well, first I have a listview which items are inflate with layout 'activity_mainlist_item', but after it's clicked it change to layout 'activity_mainlist_item_p'. After changed to layout 'B' I can't click on that item anymore. But I can click on other items.

Comment: post your selectedItem(position); method, did you change your rl_item view after item click.

Comment: Yes, I changed it to new layout after it's clicked. That's why I can't call onClick on that item. What should I do? 
public void selectedItem(int position) { this.clk_position = position; //clk_position is a global variable } 

@ReazMurshed

Comment: You don't have to change the layout. Instead you can use the same layout and by setting the visibility of an item you can achieve the desired behaviour.

Comment: so I have to create another ViewHolder, right?

Comment: Yes, you might create another ViewHolder to use different layout. Or you can use same layout and and set visibility in getView

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using single layout and divide it into two sections. First section will be visible by default and second section will be invisible. When you click on list item, make first section invisible and second section visible.

For example,

**list_item_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- replace below TextView with the layout of activity_mainlist_item.xml -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Layout 1"
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        />

    <!-- replace below TextView with the layout activity_mainlist_item_p.xml and don't forget to set android:visibility="gone"  -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Layout 2"
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

In `getView()`, try as below

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null || convertView.getTag() == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        // Assuming `ViewHolder` has layout1 and layout2.
        holder.layout1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        holder.layout2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout2);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.rl_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectedItem(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext.getApplicationContext(), DetailActivity.class);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    if (this.clk_position == position) {
        // Here, set swap the visibility or vice versa depending on your conditions
        holder.layout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.layout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return view;
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: So when we initialize its value we have to do it twice, right?

Comment: Initialize your complete layout below `holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);' and depending on the condition, set visibility and its values. No need to initialize `ViewHolder` twice. I will update my answer as well.